# tripping circuit breaker

Tags: electrical

My 15 amp circuit breaker for 2 bedrooms trips whenever either of the overhead lights are turned on but also if more than a couple of low amperage things are used in any of the receptacles (radio, low voltage light). I assumed the circuit breaker was the problem so I traded circuit breaker locations. The new circuit breaker had the same problem. The home is about 1 year old, it was professionally wired and it is not a GFI circuit.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Might there be anything else on that circuit?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Is this circuit breaker an AFCI or dual-mode - does it have a TEST button?  Do any of the appliances plugged in at this time make a feelable amount of heat?

Comment: “I traded circuit breaker locations” — what exactly did you do?  Take the wire off two different breakers and swap them? Or did you pop the breakers out and move the locations within the panel?

Comment: Please edit in a specific list of all loads on the circuit in question, not just generalizations.

Comment: There is nothing else on the circuit beyond the overhead lights and receptacles of 2 bedrooms.  Both of the overhead lights by themselves consistently trip the breaker. With the lights off combinations of a lamp, cell phone, heating pad or clock radio have tripped it. None of these except the heating pad are generating heat and there is no single item that is consistently on the receptacles during tripping. The heating pad was only used once. There is no test button. The involved breaker was 4th up from the bottom and was replaced with breakers from 2 other locations in 2 trials.

Comment: What wattages are the overhead lights in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real solution here is to actually *measure* the amount of current being drawn by the circuit.

This could be done by any number of jury-rigged methods using a multi-meter. But the safest, most effective would be to use a "clamp-amp" or "amprobe" style meter:

[image: Using a clamp-style ammeter in a circuit breaker box]

If the meter shows a load around the rating of the breaker (15 A), then you need to remove some of the loads on the circuit, and or have the rooms split into two circuits.

If the meter shows a load far below 15 A, then it's likely that the breaker is faulty and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a faulty breaker to me.

Comment: Depends what OP means by trading breaker locations.  I don’t think we can jump to this conclusion yet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We're looking for more substantial answers than this; if you feel it is correct, please add some supporting info.